# Updatable Views in Entity Framework 6

Tags: sql-server, triggers, entity-framework-6

I created a view to add a calculated Status field and renamed the underlying table.
Select is working fine.
EF is done using POCO, no EDM.
Now I need to insert/update/delete.
It fails with  the error

> Update or insert of view or function 'dbo.Clients' failed because it contains a derived or constant field.

So I added InsteadOf triggers.
Insert from TSQL works, but from EF code fails with this error

> Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0).

The profiler shows this as the last query run

```
exec sp_executesql N'INSERT [dbo].[Clients]([PersonID], [HeadOfHousehold], [FamilyID], [Complete], {various other columns}, [ExpirationDate], [LastUpdatedDate], [Status])
VALUES (@0, @1, NULL, @2, @3, @4, @5, NULL, NULL, NULL, @6, @7, @8)   
SELECT [ClientID] FROM [dbo].[Clients] 
    WHERE @@ROWCOUNT > 0 AND [ClientID] = scope_identity()'    
,N'@0 int,@1 bit,@2 bit,@3 bit,@4 nvarchar(max) ,@5 bit,@6 datetime2(7),@7 datetime2(7),@8 int',@0=26402,@1=0,@2=0,@3=0,@4=N'',@5=0,@6='2020-03-22 00:00:00',@7='2019-03-22 00:00:00',@8=0
```

The data is inserted by the trigger, but scope_identity returns NULL, because trigger, so EF thinks 0 rows were updated. Obviously, I can't get EF to use the suggested workaround of @@IDENTITY.

How do I get EF to work with an updatable view?

All the suggestions I've found so far are to update the EDMX, which I don't have.

Answer (score 0):

Travis Vandersypen posted the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44164403/how-to-insert-update-an-updatable-view-using-ef-code-first?rq=1#answers-header).
He [intercepts](https://www.skylinetechnologies.com/Blog/Skyline-Blog/December-2013/Entity-Framework-6-Intercepting-SQL-produced) and modifies the SQL before it gets sent.
I used a slightly different replacement, with @@IDENTITY, than he did.

`command.CommandText = command.CommandText.Replace("WHERE @@ROWCOUNT > 0 AND [ent_pk] = scope_identity()", "WHERE @@ROWCOUNT > 0 AND [ent_id] = @@IDENTITY");`